# ASP .NET : Folder not uploaded after deployment in AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

[Local Files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5XIud.png)

(Click above link for picture)

This is the root directory of my project running locally. This contains `Data` folder (which I manually created)

[Files During Deployment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLGuf.png)

(Click above link for picture)

This are the files that are being uploaded to Beanstalk during deployment. `Data` folder is excluded here!
How do I make sure that this folder also get pushed during deployment?